# Print Even numbers Assembly language x86

Tags: assembly, x86-16, dosbox

I have managed to write code for printing ODD numbers. Now i am trying to print Even numbers but continuously i am prompt with wrong outputs. I am not sure where i am wrong as i also tried div command. Can anyone help me in getting this fixed. Following is the code.

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H
.DATA
LF EQU '0DH'

.CODE
MAIN PROC
   MOV CX,0001H
   MOV DX,0
BACK: 
   MOV DL, CH
   OR DL, 30H
   MOV AH, 2
   INT 21H
   MOV DL, CL
   OR DL, 30H
   MOV AH, 2
   INT 21H
   CMP CL, 9
   MOV DL, 20H
   MOV AH, 2
   INT 21H
   JGE UNITSREACHED
   ADD CL, 2
   JMP UNITSUNREACHED
UNITSREACHED:
   ADD CH, 1
   MOV CL, 1
   CMP CH , 9
   JG EXIT
UNITSUNREACHED:
   JMP BACK
EXIT:
END MAIN 
MAIN ENDP
```

Comment: Well-written assembly language source shouldn't look like it just came out of a disassembler.

Comment: Please format your code and add some comment as to what you think it does.  As is, it's rather hard to read and without your comments, it's hard to understand what you intend it to do.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> CMP CL, 9
> MOV DL, 20H
> MOV AH, 2
> INT 21H
> JGE UNITSREACHED
> ```

You should never write code like this! Normally this particular `int 21h` call will preserve the flags, but you should keep the `cmp` and the `jge` close together.

```
MOV DL, 20H
MOV AH, 2
INT 21H
CMP CL, 9
JGE UNITSREACHED
```

---

Your code does indeed print "01 03 05 07 09 11 13 15 ... ".

To have it print the even numbers, you'll have to setup the `CX` register with a different value. Use `mov cx, 0000h`. You'll also need to change the value that triggers a jump to *UNITSREACHED*. This now becomes 8 (instead of 9). Use `cmp cl, 8`. And thirdly don't forget that when you increment `CH`, you need to revert `CL` to 0 (and no longer to 1).

```
MOV CX,0000H
...
CMP CL, 8
...
MOV CL, 0
```

---

Why don't you change your `JMP UNITSUNREACHED` into a `JMP BACK`? You gain nothing from jumping around needlessly.

Similarly you can optimize a bit writing:

```
CMP CH , 9
JNG BACK
```